# How to model a checking account with continuous-time compounding?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, finance, stability-in-odes

> Say you have a bank account in which your invested money yields 3% every year, continuously compounded. Also, you have estimated that you spend $1000 every month to pay your bills, that are withdrawn from this account.
>
> Create a differential model for that, find its equilibriums and determine its stability.

My problem here is that the \$1000 withdrawal is not continuous on time, it's discrete. The best I could achieve is, if $S(t)$ is the current balance: $\dot S (t) = 0,0025S(t) - 1000$. I'm using $0,0025$ as the interest rate because it yields 3% every year, so it should yield 0,25% every month. But I'm pretty confident that it's wrong. Any help would be highly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps they meant to model the expenditures as continuous as well? If the expenditures are time varying then you do not have enough information to model the problem.

Comment: Yes, I think so, but I don't know how to do that. :/

Comment: How is money expended? On a daily basis? Once per month? First day? Last day?

Comment: The problem set just says "you every-day purchases sum around $1000 per month". I'm pretty confident that the question wants me to model everything continuously but I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: It seems to me that if $t$ is to be measured in years, then $\dot S(t)=.03S-1000 \lfloor {12t}\rfloor$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x (t)$ be the amount of money in the account at time $t$ (years). Hence, if no money is spent,

$$\dot x = r x$$

where $r = \ln (1.03)$. If $\$1000$ is spent **continuously** every month, then we have the ODE

$$\dot x = r x - 12000$$

We have an equilibrium point when we have

$$\bar{x} := \frac{12000}{r} \approx \$406,000$$

in the account, as the interest earned per year then equals the amount of money expended per year. If  we have more than $\bar{x}$ in the bank, then our wealth is growing. If  we have less than $\bar{x}$ in the bank, then our wealth is decaying. Let us verify. Integrating the non-homogeneous ODE above, we obtain

$$x (t) = \bar{x} + (x_0 - \bar{x}) \, \mathrm{e}^{r t}$$

If $x_0 > \bar{x}$, our wealth is growing. If $x_0 < \bar{x}$, our wealth is decaying. If $x_0 = \bar{x}$, our wealth is stationary. Note that $\bar{x}$ is an **unstable** equilibrium point.

Comment: Thanks a lot, got it! In your solution, the time is measured in years. If we represent time in months, the correct interest rate should be $r=\frac{\ln (1.03)}{12}$, right?

Comment: @RaulGuarini Yes. And the ODE becomes $\dot x = r x - 1000$.

Comment: @RaulGuarini Why doesn't $r = .03$ or $\frac{.03}{12}$?

Comment: @user10478 If $r = \ln (1.03)$, then $$e^{rt} = \left( \exp (r) \right)^t = \left( \exp(\ln( 1.03 )) \right)^t = (1 + 0.03)^t$$

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Hmm, is this because the problem says "yields $3\%$ every year," whereas $r$ would be $.03$ if it said "annual interest rate of $3\%$"?

Comment: @user10478 That is part of it. Note that $e^{0.03} \neq 1.03$.

Answer (score 0):

The money flow consists of two contributions
$$
\dot{S} = \dot{S}_y + \dot{S}_m
$$
with the continous contribution
$$
\dot{S}_y = a S \quad (*)
$$
where $a$ must be adjusted to give the yearly interest rate such that 
$$
S_y(1\text{y}) = (1 + p) S_y(0\text{y})
$$ 
for $p = 3\% = 3/100$ and the monthly part
$$
\dot{S}_m = -M \sum_{k=1}^\infty \delta(t - k\cdot 1\text{m})
$$
with $M = 1000 \$$.

Determining $a$ from $p$: Equation $(*)$ means
$$
S_y(t) = S_y(0\text{y}) e^{at}
$$ 
and 
$$
S_y(1\text{y}) = S_y(0\text{y}) e^{a \cdot 1 \text{y}} = (1 + p) S_y(0\text{y})
$$
so $a = \ln(1+p)/1\text{y}$.
In summary:
$$
\dot{S} = S(0\text{y}) \, (1+p)^{t/1\text{y}} - M \sum_{k=1}^\infty \delta(t - k\cdot 1\text{m})
$$

Answer (score 0):

The ballance must be sufficient to generate $1,000 / month in cash flow

$B(e^{0.0025}-1) = 1000\\
B = \dfrac{1000}{e^{0.0025}-1} = \$399,500$